# How to acces previous element in an ArrayList using "this"

Tags: java, processing

I would like to access previous element from the reserved name "this"  like that :

```
paper.lines.get(this-1);
```

Is there a way to do it simply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `this` is an element in the List and you want the elements located before it, you need :

```
paper.lines.get(paper.lines.indexOf(this) - 1);
```

Of course this code lacks validations, since `this` may not be found in the List, or it may be the first element of the List. In both cases you'll get an exception.

So, safer code would be:

```
int index = paper.lines.indexOf(this);
if (index > 0) {
    return paper.lines.get(index - 1);
}
```

Comment: I made it in another way final, indexOf(this) is a little bit tricky. when I create my object I set an id parameter... way more simple...